# how to enable support of ogonek characters in linux

Tags: linux, docker, fonts, containers, amazon-ecs

Characters such as "ęą" are not recognized on my docker container, they are just omitted. I use phantom js to convert an HTML page into thumbnail. Html page contains characters like "ęą" on the page. So while generating thumbnail from it Ogonek characters [ęą] are ignored. I am sure this mus be happening due to Ogonek font not installed on linux [I am using amazon linux]. So want to know the font packages which needs to be installed on amazon linux to enable support for Ogonek  charecters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Addition of below fonts from amazonlinux library worked for me ...

dejavu-fonts-common.noarch dejavu-lgc-sans-fonts.noarch dejavu-lgc-sans-mono-fonts.noarch dejavu-lgc-serif-fonts.noarch dejavu-sans-fonts.noarch dejavu-sans-mono-fonts.noarch dejavu-serif-fonts.noarch